# conda: Install a local package tarball

Tags: conda

I've downloaded a pre-built conda package named as a `.tar.bz2` file, and I'd like to install it.

I tried simply providing the path to the tarball:

```
conda install /path/to/downloads/mypackage-2.40-py37hd618bb5_1.tar.bz2
```

...but that doesn't install any of the package dependencies!

How can I install the local package *including all dependencies?*

Comment: You could try adding `--update-deps`, but with the bullshit tool like `conda`, you never know what's it going to do. You may get lucky though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local "channel" and install it from there.

1. Create a directory to serve as the local channel, with a subdirectory for your platform (OS).
2. Move your package tarball into that subdirectory.
3. Run `conda index` on the local channel directory.
4. Run `conda install -c file://${my_local_channel}`

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/my-local-channel/osx-64
mv ~/Downloads/mypackage-2.40-py37hc48c483_1.tar.bz2 /tmp/my-local-channel/osx-64
conda index /tmp/my-local-channel
conda install -c file:///tmp/my-local-channel mypackage
```